# Append .csv files to existing excel workbook template

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to take a varying number of csv files and copy them into an existing excel workbook as new sheets for each csv file. The issue is that I am copying them into a template that already has 2 sheets. With my current code, those template sheets are overwritten. I have seen many questions around similar issues and have not found one that will add csv files to an existing workbook without overwriting the current sheets. Here is what I have been using:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('Summary_Template.xlsx')

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    csvfile = os.path.basename(csvfile)
    worksheet = Workbook.add_worksheet(workbook) #wroskeet with csv file name
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col) #write the csv file content into it
workbook.close()
```

I tried a similar version using the xlwt module but one my csv files has more than 65535 lines which causes an error with this module. Aside from that I do not care what modules are used, I just need to append the csv files to my template without overwriting existing sheets.

Since I have successfully put all the csv files into a .xls workbook, I would settle for a way to merge two workbooks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wondering if get_sheet_names() in openpyxl.workbook.workbook might help? Iterate, store, then add to? http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=get_sheet#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.get_sheet_by_name